# Parse Enum Output with Flask Marshmallow Schema

Tags: python, schema, dump, flask-marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I have a question about flask marshmallow schema. So, I create models like an example below.

```
class ID(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)


class Timestamp(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now(), nullable=False)
    updated = db.Column(


class Checklist(ID, Timestamp):
    __tablename__ = "checklist"

    partner_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey("partner.id"), nullable=False)
    statement_status = db.Column(
        db.Enum(StatementStatus), nullable=False, default=StatementStatus.NOT_SELECTED
    )
    statement_accuracy = db.Column(
        db.Enum(StatementAccuracy),
        nullable=False,
        default=StatementAccuracy.NOT_SELECTED,
    )
    update_status = db.Column(
        db.Enum(UpdateStatus), nullable=False, default=UpdateStatus.NOT_SELECTED
    )
    annual_text_return = db.Column(
        db.Enum(AnnualReturnStatus),
        nullable=False,
        default=AnnualReturnStatus.NOT_SELECTED,
    )
```

Then i have schema like this:

```
from flask_marshmallow.sqla import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema
class ChecklistSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):

class Meta:
    model = Checklist
    include_fk = True
```

Is it possible to have output enum like

```
statement_status: {"value": NOT_SELECTED, "name": "Not Selected"}
```

after I dump? Thx before

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer.

1. create class that serialize field enum to dict

   class EnumToDictionary(fields.Field):

> ```
> def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj, **kwargs):
>     if value is None:
>         return None
>     return {"name": value.name, "value": value.value}
> ```

2. use the class

> ```
> class ChecklistSchema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
> statement_status = EnumToDictionary(attribute=("statement_status"))
> statement_accuracy = EnumToDictionary(attribute="statement_accuracy")
> update_status = EnumToDictionary(attribute="update_status")
> annual_text_return = EnumToDictionary(attribute="annual_text_return")
>
> class Meta:
>     model = Checklist
>     include_fk = True
> ```